# How to replace the authenticated javax.security.Principal in JSF context?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jaas

I want to create a "Impersonate" feature in my JSF application. This functionality would provide the Administrator with the ability to access the application authenticated with a low-level user without even knowing the password.

I though it would be a simple `setUserPrincipal`, similar to what I use to get the current logged in User
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal()`, but I couldn't find any "setUserPrincipal" method inside `javax.faces.context.ExternalContext`...

In short, what I want is to programmatically change the current logged in user, so the admin can impersonate any other user, without informing the credentials. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Leave the principal alone and just change the roles. Make sure you can change them back :-|

Comment: I always create a (small) wrapper around the authentication mechanism where I put 'impersonate' things. So I never need to touch the authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise against playing with authentication/authorization unless you really don't have alternatives.

Anyway, leave out JSF, it comes in the game too late.

The simplest way is to provide a customized request, supplied with a filter:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "impersonateFilter", urlPatterns = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
public class ImpersonateFilter implements Filter
{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        ImpersonateRequest impersonateRequest = new ImpersonateRequest(httpRequest);
        chain.doFilter(impersonateRequest, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public static class ImpersonateRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
    {
        protected Principal principal;

        public ImpersonateRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
        {
            super(request);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if(session != null)
            {
                principal = (Principal) session.getAttribute(ImpersonateRequest.class.getName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Principal getUserPrincipal()
        {
            if(principal == null)
            {
                principal = super.getUserPrincipal();
            }

            return principal;
        }

        public void setUserPrincipal(Principal principal)
        {
            this.principal = principal;
            getSession().setAttribute(ImpersonateRequest.class.getName(), principal);
        }

        @Override
        public String getRemoteUser()
        {
            return principal == null ? super.getRemoteUser() : principal.getName();
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this should suffice.